# Let $[x_{ij}]_{i=1,\dots k;j=1,\dots n}$ be a matrix consisting of random variables. How may generators has ideal $I$ consisting of maximal minors.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

We are considering standard polynomial ring over field.

Let $[x_{ij}]_{i=1,\dots k;j=1,\dots n}$ be $n\times k$ ($n\geq k$) a matrix consisting of random variables. Let's define ideal $I$ as ideal generated by minors $k\times k$ of above matrix. State how many generators has this ideal.

I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. First we need to find number of minors which is ${{n}\choose{k}}$. From these generators we cannot remove any because every monomial of these homogeneous generators is present only once. So all minors are not divisible by each other.

Of course non-zero remain of the division does not indicate that our generator isn't already in the ideal. But construction of Grobner basis out of initial minors would lead to addition (if any) of polynomials with leading terms of higher monomial order.

Comment: What does $\binom{k}{n}$ mean? The number of $k\times k$ minors is $\binom{n}{k}^2$.

Comment: @Mohan, we consider maximal minors, so we only need to pick $k$ columns from $n$ columns. So there is ${n}\choose{k}$ such possibilities.

Comment: I think your question is whether all maximal minors form a minimal system of generators for the ideal they generate. Am I right?

Comment: @user26857, yeah. Although I am not sure if it is obvious that there cannot be nonhomogeneous system of generators which is smaller than one generated by maximal minors. I know that every homogeneous minimal system of generators has the same amount of polynomials.